# raise self.model.DoesNotExist( users.models.Profile.DoesNotExist: Profile matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm, Profile


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(
                request, "Your account has been created! Your ar now able to login.")
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        # p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(
        #     request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your account has been updated!")
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = profile)
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import CustomUser


@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(email=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**models.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm, Profile


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            messages.success(
                request, "Your account has been created! Your ar now able to login.")
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})


@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        # p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(
        #     request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        prf = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = prf)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your account has been updated!")
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        prf = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = prf)
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import Profile
from .models import CustomUser
from django import forms


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['name', 'email','registration', 'password1', 'password2']

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['name', 'email','registration']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .models import Profile
from .models import CustomUser



class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'user')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'user')
    list_filter = ('user', )
    list_per_page = 20

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

Here I'm extending User Model using AbstractBaseUser.
I want to add a new Profile.
and I'm adding the Profile Model with CustomUser model using OneToOneField.
My register and login is working.
But can't see the profiles and it gives error
But I'm facing the above problem please help me!!

Comment: Share your models and full error traceback

Comment: Error traceback is pasted in this link.
https://pastebin.com/dUvWtxS4

Comment: this is the error causing line ```prf = Profile.objects.get(user = request.user)```, btw I don't see any variables ```prf``` in the shared code?

Comment: I thought since profile is the name of function. Maybe it might be causing the error.
so changed profile to prf.

Comment: then update the post too..

Comment: Also how can I show you the models?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240054/discussion-between-zeshan-ahmed-nobin-and-sumithran).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I was having trouble with `Profile.objects.create` in my signals.py
It was imported from apps.py.
and in settings.py installed apps I was including my `appname` directly.
by writing `'users'`.
changing users to `'users.apps.UsersConfig'` solved the bug.